# How can I use JavaScript on the server and client while sharing some code between the two?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-side, server-side

So I've got a little side project I want to work on for fun, but I have searched around a bit for examples/libs/frameworks that could be used to share as much code as possible from the client to the server.

So far my only experience is client side JavaScript, but I thought it might be cool to use the same language on the server and even cooler to be able to use the exact same code on both.

The nicest thing to me would be to write a `Model` for example a `Dog` and write validation funcs and methods for said `Dog` model and be able to have the exact same validation/business logic on the client as well as on the server, but only have to write it once.

Anybody do something like this already or something even better? Any examples would be awesome.

Comment: You already know about NodeJS, so I'm not sure what else you're looking for. Seems like all that's left is to write the code you want to share.

Comment: I see someone voted to close this. At the very least I'm looking for a way to share logic in a structured manner in my models using and MVC or MVVM pattern.

Comment: Some of the client-side frameworks can be used server-side -- e.g., [backbone](https://www.npmjs.org/package/backbone), [angular](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular). And, [browserify](http://browserify.org/) can help with using server-side code on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the modules which could be reused both on the server and client and write them into the separate library. Then you can include this library both in nodejs and your front end javascript.

One particular example of such a library which I used and like is chess.js (https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js)

> chess.js is a Javascript chess library that is used for chess move
>   generation/validation, piece placement/movement, and
>   check/checkmate/stalemate detection

If you write for example chess game server, you can use it for validation and keeping the state of the game both on the server and in the browser.

The code is wrapped in one big function which when loaded in the browser is available on the window.

this line of code makes it also available as node.js module in node environment:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') exports.Chess = Chess;
```